# How to test rake task in Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, mocking, automated-tests, rake-task

I have a rake task in my rails application that published jobs to facebook. And then changes some model values. **So one way to test the rake task is to invoke the rake task and check values that have been changed.**

```
test 'z' do
    # setup some data
    Rake::Task['job:publish_to_facebook'].invoke
    Rake::Task['job:publish_to_facebook'].reenable
    # assert table values that has been changed. 
end
```

But how I can test whether jobs are successfully published on facebook? Is there any better strategy except using **capybara** and **selenium-webdriver** ?

Even if i use **stubbing and mocking** then how can i verify that my jobs are published on facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most tests *should not* contact an external API, mainly because it will slow down tests and you might also run into rate limits.

> Even if i use stubbing and mocking then how can i verify that my jobs are published on facebook?

The point of stubbing and mocking is precisely *not* to publish to Facebook. Instead, you would create a class called `Facebook` (for example) with a method like `def post_message(message)`. This is the app's front door to Facebook, all calls to Facebook go through this class. Then you can use a library like Mocha to overwrite `def post_message` during testing. You can use it to verify that the application is attempting to post a message, and verify the message itself is correct. It won't actually post the message.

As I mentioned, you do want to make some tests with real calls to Facebook (though not many). These could be in a test like you've shown above, which is an integration test, or it could also be a smaller unit test of the `Facebook` class I suggested above, which would be a better starting point. For this purpose, you'd want to establish a test account on Facebook. Then your test should clear all messages in the setup and use Facebook's API to verify that the messages were actually posted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain overwrite method with mocha. Means how the method would be tested using mocha? As you suggested if i move post_message to s separate class then how i will test that method is doing its job. Forget about checking message on facebook

Comment: I simply want to test that post_message is doing its job.

Comment: Take a look at http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/ for mocking. But if your only concern is to test that you're posting to Facebook - and not worried about the logic for constructing the message - then that's what I mean in the second paragraph, ie I would create a simple Facebook class for all of the app's Facebook's needs, and write a FacebookTest class in the way I mentioned. That part has nothing to do with mocking. You ideally need all three kinds of tests (unit test with mocking, unit test to check calling external API, and integration test to test it all).